# Puppet how to check that exec resource is not getting applied

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am working on a project which contains a module with nearly 100 of exec resources guarded by creates attribute to ensure that exec resource is idempotent.
On applying puppet class, it just logs only those resources which are getting applied but not the other resources which are not getting applied.

I am trying to refactor module and want to get list of all resources in that module along with their status like applied , not applied etc. If any of the resource is not getting applied then also the reason why it's not getting applied.

Is there any way to produce such a report in puppet.

Thanks

Comment: If you run Puppet with --debug, it'll show the full details of why or why not an exec is getting run. Does that help?

Comment: This is horrifically bad practice. Don't build modules that comprise dozens of `exec` resources. Puppet is not a scripting language. Build a script that performs all the steps in one shot. Build another script that checks whether everything is in place, or if you need another shot.